# How can I add a social tag to a page by using a custom script?

Tags: development, social

I wrote a script which I think is supposed to tag a page with a URL. I copied the URL which SharePoint uses to tag a page with "I Like It" when someone clicks on the I like it button.

The URL is "_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag"

```
$("a").click(function(){

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag",
        data: '{"targetPage":"http://url/calendar.aspx","title":"Documents - All Documents","quickTagId":0}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(msg){
          alert(msg);
        }

      });

      return false; 
});
```

The script does not work and the error in the logs says "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/AddQuickTag'."

Any Ideas? Is it possible to write such a script?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your own web service for this. As you probably seen "socialdatainternalservice.json" contains the word "internal".

Answer (score 0):

I would user Fiddler to compare the POST requests.

One using the standard method and one using your script. See if you spot any differences.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found nothing special, but I did find that the standard method is sending a request digest. Right now, I am trying to add a tag using the API.